# Writing a shell in C for linux, exec for one certain process is infinitely looping

Tags: c, linux, shell, exec, fork

This is the relevant snippet of code:

```
if(!strcmp(args[0],"run")){
                pid_t pid = fork();
                if(pid == 0){
                  execvp(args[1], args);
                  fprintf(stdout, "Process could not be found in this directory\n");
                  kill((int)getpid(), SIGKILL);
                }
                else{
                    if(pid < 0)
                        exit(1);

                    fprintf(stdout, "PID of Process = %d\n", pid);
                    int success = waitpid(pid, &childExitStatus, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);

                    if(success == -1)
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

            }
```

Now when I run a process like Libre Office math, it will only open one instance of it. However, when I try to open xterm using this code, it will continue to exec over and over, creating many instances of xterm before I do an interrupt and exit. I don't see any loops that would cause this to happen. Any insight into why this would be?

Comment: Maybe your bug is elsewhere. Look into existing free software shells.

Comment: Try `execvp(args[1], args + 1)`, maybe xterm is confused by the first argument being `run` instead of `xterm`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks I'll be sure to look through the entirety of my code. This is more of an exercise for me though, getting to know the ins and outs of processes in linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `execvp()` call is incorrect because it passes an additional argument "run" at the start. When executing `xterm` in this manner, the effect is similar to `xterm xterm` and has xterm use `xterm` as the shell. The new xterm inherits a `SHELL` environment variable that causes it to start another xterm, until limits are exhausted.

Comment: This was the solution, just needed to pass it the next address instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to jilles' answer to your immediate problem, you should know that calling `fprintf` if `execvp` fails is unwise as it can lead to duplication of previously-buffered output.  It also means you cannot safely use `vfork`, which can still be a valuable optimization (particularly if the parent process uses a lot of memory).

There is no *good* way to report an `exec` failure, unfortunately.  I tend to just do

```
if (pid == 0) {
    execvp(...);
    /* if we got here, something bad happened */
    _exit(127);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind and change my code up